# The effect of number of functions in a C++ library

Tags: c++

Suppose now two C++ libraries are available: one library has all the functions that will be needed by the program ( a C++ application program that will invoke the library), and the other one not only has the necessary functions that will be needed by the program but also has other functions that will not not used by the program. We assume that for the common functions in both libraries they are implemented in the same manner. My question is: when the program uses  the library to perform a certain task, what's the effect of the library on the performance of the program?

The reason why I asked this question is because when developing a c++ library I often wrote some additional functions, which may not be invoked by the users of the library but are important for debugging. When the library is finished, I have two choices: one is to keep these auxiliary functions and the other is removing them or using other strategies of keep them (for example, define MACRO to disable these functions). If keeping these auxiliaries functions will not deteriorate the performance, I would like to keep them.

Comment: Define a macro and add your debug code under it. The unused functions will unnecessarily increase the size of the binaries (.o) generated.

Comment: I believe it's good idea to multiple function which may not use in currently but expected to use in future. I do not have static but I saw in my company...

Comment: Have you made some performance test? Is there anything that suggests that there is (or is not) a performance issue with more or less functions?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Not yet, and I asked this question for a general idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything else being the same, there will be no performance difference.

In addition, if the library is a static library, the linker will not include the functions that are not used, and the executables will have the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have written a static library that I guess you have. Then the only difference it will create is that the static library functionality will be part of you executable no matter if you use it or not.

I don't think it will hurt you in terms of speed but yes it will occupy a lot more space since a copy of lib will be created with you executable.